# SQL 2012 code improvement joining tables and sum counts

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, view

I am querying a SQL database and need to join two tables (SCCM 2012 R2). The code I have below works but I was wondering if this can be improved or achieved by another method other than creating a view and querying from that.

When I just use a join without the view, the output is incorrect because it shows me multiple 'Product' columns, when I want that to be unique and SUM the 'count' columns when multiple 'product' columns with the same value exist. The final part is to calculate the difference between the 'effectivequantity' (AI_NON_MS_LICENSE) column and the previously calculated count.

(EDIT - now a temporary table)

```
DROP TABLE #VIEW_LICENSES


CREATE TABLE #VIEW_LICENSES (

"Total Used" int,
"Product" char(30),
"License Status" char(30),
"Version" char(30)  )

INSERT INTO #VIEW_LICENSES ("Total Used", "Product", "License Status", "Version")

SELECT SUM("COUNT") AS 'Total Used', Tag1Name AS 'Product', Tag2Name AS 'Version', Tag3Name AS 'License Status'

FROM v_LU_SoftwareList_Editable LEFT JOIN AI_NON_MS_LICENSE

ON v_LU_SoftwareList_Editable.Tag1Name = Name

GROUP BY Tag1Name, Tag2Name, Tag3Name

GO


select "Total Used" AS 'Total Used' , Product AS 'Product',  "License Status" AS 'License Status', EffectiveQuantity AS 'Licensed Amount', (EffectiveQuantity)-("Total Used") AS "Remaining Licenses"

from #VIEW_LICENSES LEFT JOIN AI_NON_MS_LICENSE

ON #VIEW_LICENSES.Product = Name

GROUP BY [Product], [Total Used],[License Status],[EffectiveQuantity]

GO
```

Comment: Be careful here. It looks like v_LU_SoftwareList_Editable is already a view? I know it seems perfectly logical that you could nest views but in sql server it absolutely a no go. The query optimizer is unable to generate a good plan and the performance will suffer horribly. To help with the question at hand this would be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @SeanLange   Do you mean, that a view should only reference base tables, not other views?

Comment: The v_LU_SoftwareList_Editable is a view. I viewed the execution plan, I don't really know what to look out for here as a concern but most of the steps have a cost of 0%

Comment: @CPMunich yes that is correct. There are dozens and dozens of articles out there about this. Here is one of them. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/

Comment: @JamesD22 I would try to rewrite your new view by using the same queries as in those other nested views. The optimizer will be better able to generate a decent execution plan. The biggest obstacle in providing more detailed help is the lack of details.

Comment: @JamesD22  I cannot post an answer to this question but what I would like to say is the following: If you do not want to create a view and query from that, then maybe Common Table Expressions (CTE) is something for you.
Inside the CTE you specify the SELECT-Statement as you would in your view. In the outer SELECT you query the CTE with its name.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms175972(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: I have also just found out that creating views in the database is not supported by Microsoft, so I need to use a temporary table instead. I have changed my original post because didn't have enough characters left here. Thanks for all your advice so far.

Comment: "I have also just found out that creating views in the database is not supported by Microsoft"???? What does that mean? Is this a microsoft application you are using or something?

Comment: Yes, 'SCCM 2012 R2' as stated in my original post. I was asking the same question on the Microsoft forums where I generally got a stock response to read articles which didn't help. Until someone pointed out the support aspect.

Comment: Which steps in the execution plan are using the highest percentage of resources?

Comment: The mix of view #temp is just plain confusing.  Clean up the question.